# How to set a background image in Ionic 4

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework, ionic4

[image: Ionic]

How do you set a background image in Ionic 4?  I've tried several ways to no avail.

I'm following this tutorial:
https://javebratt.com/ionic-firebase-tutorial-auth/

I've also tried

--background: #fff url('../../assets/images/cover.jpg') no-repeat center center / cover;
}

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I'm using Ionic 4

```css
ion-content {
  .background{
        background-image: url('../../../assets/img/login-image.jpg');
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        background-size: cover;
  }
form {
  margin-bottom: 32px;
  button {
    margin-top: 20px !important;
  }
}

p {
  font-size: 0.8em;
  color: #d2d2d2;
}

ion-label {
  margin-left: 5px;
}

ion-input {
  padding: 5px;
}

.invalid {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ff6153;
}

.error-message {
  min-height: 2.2rem;
  ion-label {
    margin: 2px 0;
  }
}
}
```

```html
<ion-content class="background">
<form [formGroup]="loginForm">
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label position="stacked">Email</ion-label>
    <ion-input
      formControlName="email"
      type="email"
      placeholder="Your email address"
      [class.invalid]="!loginForm.controls['email'].valid &&
      loginForm.controls['email'].touched"
    >
    </ion-input>
  </ion-item>
  <ion-item
    class="error-message"
    *ngIf="!loginForm.controls['email'].valid &&
       loginForm.controls['email'].touched"
  >
    <ion-label>Please enter a valid email address.</ion-label>
  </ion-item>

  <ion-item>
    <ion-label position="stacked">Password</ion-label>
    <ion-input
      formControlName="password"
      type="password"
      placeholder="Your password"
      [class.invalid]="!loginForm.controls['password'].valid&& loginForm.controls['password'].touched"
    >
    </ion-input>
    </ion-item>
  <ion-item
    class="error-message"
    *ngIf="!loginForm.controls['password'].valid
      && loginForm.controls['password'].touched"
  >
    <ion-label>Your password needs more than 6 characters.</ion-label>
  </ion-item>

  <ion-button (click)="loginUser(loginForm)" expand="block" [disabled]="!loginForm.valid">
    Log In
  </ion-button>
</form>

<ion-button expand="block" fill="clear" routerLink="/signup">
  Create a new account
</ion-button>

<ion-button expand="block" fill="clear" routerLink="/reset-password">
  I forgot my password 
</ion-button>
  <ion-footer no-shadow>
    <div>
      <button ion-button icon-left block>
              Login with Google
      </button>
    </div>
      <div>
      <button ion-button icon-left block>
        Login with Facebook
      </button>
    </div>
  </ion-footer>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: Is the image path correct? Do you get any error in the console like cannot get the image?

Comment: Yes it's correct.  When I alter it in anyway is when I get a console error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked

```
ion-content {
  --background: #fff url("../../../assets/img/login-image.jpg") no-repeat center center / cover;
}
```

Answer (score 9):

If you need more control, set the css variable --background to none first, then specify the usual css properties:

```
ion-content {
  --background: none;
  background-image: url('../../../assets/img/login-image.jpg');
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

This worked in browser and real device both:

```
 --background: url('/assets/recover_form_bg.jpg') no-repeat center/cover fixed;
```

Don't use ../../../assets path for image because it's not work in real device.

Answer (score 0):

**Let's try these steps and see how it goes:**

You can select ion-content directly in your CSS instead of creating another CSS class. I am assuming you need a background image for a page. So grab the whole page by **ion-content** element. Then use usual CSS properties for an element background. But when using Ionic make sure relative paths are incorrect form. For example I think your assets(image) path is not right. That's why ionic is not able to render/find it on device. The code snippet I am giving below is working for me.

```
 page-details {
     ion-content {
      --background: none;
      background-image: url("assets/imgs/img_bg_floral.png");
      -webkit-background-image: url("../../assets/imgs/img_bg_floral.png");          
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: cover;
     }
```

Comment: That didn't work either.  I'm pretty sure the relative path is correct because I changed it around a little and received errors when the image wasn't reachable.

Comment: Glad to know you have found your solution.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested in android. Its working fine for me.

SCSS:

```
ion-content {
  --background: #34B0D2 url('../../assets/yourimage.jpeg') no-repeat center top fixed;
  background-size: cover;      
}
```